# Parse PFInstallation change fields error

Tags: parse-platform

I am using parse push notifications in Xcode and am storing userIDs in a column "recipients ids" in the installation table....

When the users log out I want to empty the recipients ids or else when they log out they will still receive notifications..

For some reason if I log in and out n amount of times it randomly will get stuck and the recipient id will NOT UPDATE!? 
And i get this error

Error: deviceType must be specified in this operation (Code: 135, Version: 1.2.21)

```
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setObject: @" " forKey:@"recipientsId"];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

Comment: Saw a similar complaint over in the Google Groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/qttpAwCv8IA